# CMD string variable multi-line output without additional spaces and carriage returns

Tags: cmd

I am passing a parameter to cmd.exe which writes some multi-line text to the windows clipboard. The parameter needs to be a single line. I currently have:

```
(echo This && echo.is a && echo. && echo.muilti-line && echo. && echo.example)|clip
```

which outputs:

```
This·¶

is·a·¶

·¶

multi-line·¶

·¶

example¶

¶
```

What changes are necessary to output:

```
This¶

is·a¶

¶

multi-line¶

¶

example¶
```

(i.e. no leading/trailing spaces or carriage return)??

Comment: Echo prints lines. Nearly everything in command prompt is lines. `Clip < C:windows\win.ini` puts the exact text on clipboard.

Comment: CatCat, where exactly would I use    Clip < C:windows\win.ini   ? In cmd or send the event directly? If directly, what is the syntax to include a text string to write to the clipboard?

Comment: In `CMD` as you are redirecting StdIn.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of a command to write some carriage return inclusive text to the clipboard using Clip < C:windows\win.ini ? I have been trying unsuccessfully. I am interested to see if it handles all the special characters.

Comment: The point you put what you want in a file and redirect it to `clip` as I've redirected the multiline **win.ini**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd /c "echo.This& echo.is a& echo.& echo.multi-line& echo.& echo.example"| clip
```

Comment: This might be a different question, but might also change the solution. I have found that it cannot handle the following special characters in the original text: " < > |  Is there a way to escape these so they pass through to the output?

Comment: `"` cannot be escaped in a quoted string. `<`, `>`, and `|` can be escaped with `^`. There were no special characters in the original question. Maybe it would be simpler to write the text to a temporary file and %CLIPFILE% run `clip < "%CLIPFILE%"`.

Comment: Thanks again AlexP, yes you did answer my original question 100%. I wasn't aware of the special character issue at the time. Do you know if it's possible to substitute some string like XXXXX with " in the output?

Comment: It all depends on the specific use case, which is not described in the question. However, I really do believe that the easiest approach is to write the text to a temporary file and have `clip` read the file and place the contents on the clipboard; this would be more general and easier to maintain.